# ngc not compiling project using not typed third party libraries

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

The project uses a third party library with no types defined. As the project is developed using Angular CLI (version 1.0.0-beta.29), the library is declared in **typings.d.ts**. In my case: declare module ‘xml2js-es6-promise’;

Project compiles and is served fine with tsc, but no with ngc. 
The error trace:

```
Cannot find module ‘xml2js-es6-promise’
```

The tscconfig:

```
{
 “compilerOptions”: {
 “baseUrl”: “.”,
 “declaration”: true,
 “stripInternal”: true,
 “experimentalDecorators”: true,
 “strictNullChecks”: false,
 “noImplicitAny”: false,
 “module”: “es2015”,
 “moduleResolution”: “node”,
 “paths”: {
 “@angular/core”: [“node_modules/@angular/core”],
 “rxjs/*”: [“node_modules/rxjs/*”],
 “xml2js-es6-promise”:[“node_modules/xml2js-es6-promise”]
 },
 “rootDir”: “.”,
 “outDir”: “dist”,
 “sourceMap”: true,
 “inlineSources”: true,
 “target”: “es5”,
 “skipLibCheck”: true,
 “lib”: [
 “es2015”, 
 “dom”
 ]
 },
 “files”: [
 “index.ts”
 ],
 “angularCompilerOptions”: {
 “strictMetadataEmit”: true
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The third party library should include the ngsummary.json files produced while ngc compiling (aot). Otherwise you couldn't compile your project ahead of time.